How to Compute Teacher-Forced Accuracy (TFA) for Hugging Face Models While Handling EOS Tokens?
I am trying to compute Teacher-Forced Accuracy (TFA) for Hugging Face models, ensuring the following:

EOS Token Handling: The model should be rewarded for predicting the first EOS token.
Ignoring Padding: Any padding tokens (beyond the first EOS) should be ignored during accuracy calculation.
Right-Shifted Input: The inputs are shifted correctly for teacher-forced training.
List item

Here’s the full code I wrote:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

def compute_tfa(model, tokenizer, input_texts):
    """
    Computes Teacher-Forced Accuracy (TFA), rewarding the model for correctly predicting
    the first EOS token while ignoring predictions for padding tokens.

    Parameters:
        model: The language model (Hugging Face CausalLM).
        tokenizer: The tokenizer corresponding to the model.
        input_texts: List of input texts to compute TFA.

    Returns:
        TFA score as a float.
    """
    # Tokenize input texts
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token  # Use EOS as the pad token
    inputs = tokenizer(input_texts, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
    input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
    
    # Create right-shifted input by adding the EOS token at the beginning
    eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
    right_shifted_input_ids = torch.cat([
        torch.full((input_ids.shape[0], 1), eos_token_id, dtype=torch.long),  # Add EOS token
        input_ids[:, :-1]
    ], dim=1)

    # Perform a forward pass with the right-shifted inputs
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids=right_shifted_input_ids)
        logits = outputs.logits  # Shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)

    # Compute predictions
    predicted_token_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)  # Shape: (batch_size, sequence_length)

    # Find the first EOS position in each sequence
    eos_positions = (input_ids == eos_token_id).int().argmax(dim=1)  # Shape: (batch_size,)

    # Mask to ignore tokens after the first EOS
    sequence_lengths = input_ids.size(1)
    mask = torch.arange(sequence_lengths).unsqueeze(0).to(input_ids.device)
    mask = mask < eos_positions.unsqueeze(1)

    # Include the first EOS token in the mask
    mask.scatter_(1, eos_positions.unsqueeze(1), 1)

    # Apply the mask to filter predictions and labels
    filtered_predictions = predicted_token_ids[mask]
    filtered_labels = input_ids[mask]

    # Compute accuracy
    correct_predictions = (filtered_predictions == filtered_labels).float()
    accuracy = correct_predictions.mean().item()

    return accuracy

def main():
    # Define models and their URLs
    models_and_urls = {
        "google/gemma-2-2b": "https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-2-2b",
        "meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B": "https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B",
        "gpt2": "https://huggingface.co/gpt2"
    }

    # Define input texts
    input_texts = [
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
        "Artificial Intelligence is transforming the world of science."
    ]

    # Test each model
    for model_name, model_url in models_and_urls.items():
        print(f"Testing model: {model_name} ({model_url})")
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

        # Compute TFA
        tfa_score = compute_tfa(model, tokenizer, input_texts)
        print(f"Teacher-Forced Accuracy (TFA) for {model_name}: {tfa_score:.4f}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

What I Need Help With:

EOS Token Masking: Is the masking logic I implemented for ignoring tokens after the first EOS correct? Specifically, I used:
mask = torch.arange(sequence_lengths).unsqueeze(0).to(input_ids.device)
mask = mask < eos_positions.unsqueeze(1)
mask.scatter_(1, eos_positions.unsqueeze(1), 1)

Is this the best way to ensure only tokens up to and including the first EOS are considered?

Right-Shifted Input: I prepend the EOS token to the input like this:
right_shifted_input_ids = torch.cat([
    torch.full((input_ids.shape[0], 1), eos_token_id, dtype=torch.long),
    input_ids[:, :-1]
], dim=1)

Is this a standard way to handle the right-shift for teacher-forced evaluation?

Generalization: The code is designed to evaluate multiple models, such as google/gemma-2-2b, meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B, and gpt2. Are there any additional considerations or best practices I should follow for TFA computation across diverse models?

Performance Optimization: Is there a more efficient way to compute the mask and apply it to the predictions and labels? My current method seems to work but might be suboptimal for larger datasets.



cross: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-compute-teacher-forced-accuracy-tfa-for-hugging-face-models-while-handling-eos-tokens/126403
cross2: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-compute-teacher-forced-accuracy-tfa-for-hugging-face-models-while-handling-eos-tokens/213435


ref: https://gist.github.com/brando90/66a58ad38f702cf92afa7f7e03877530

ref: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-compute-teacher-forced-accuracy-tfa-for-hugging-face-models-while-handling-eos-tokens/213435

ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-compute-teacher-forced-accuracy-tfa-for-hugging-face-models-while-handling-eos-tokens/126403
